# How should i treat this data, as a covariate or as a factor?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, continuous-data, minitab

In my research group, I'm in charge of the statistical analysis of the data generated by the team, but I am fairly new to all of these statistics. So, I have this ambient temperature data (which on the experiment was controlled) and I don't know if I should treat it as a covariate or as a factor.

As I understand covariate is when you have a continuous variable that is not at all in your control but still is measured and a factor is a discrete variable under your control.

On one hand, I lean to analyze it as a factor because it was controlled and I want to do some media comparisons and apparently I can't do this on MINITAB if I'm treating the data as a covariate.

But on the other side, our final goal is to simulate a household refrigerator so a covariate would be a better approach (I think) because in a regular home you cannot control the ambient temperature so easily.

Can anyone help me to see the limitations and advantages of both ways of work, or if I'm missing something important? As I said I have not much experience with data analysis besides my DoE and probability undergrad classes.

P.S.: If it is not too much, it would be of much help also if you can suggest to me some lectures and books to look further into statistics.

Comment: How is the math different?

Comment: I don't know the specifics because MINITAB Support doesn't clarify it. But there is a difference since the ANOVA results change a lot